# Where I should use img.onload in this situation?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Help me please to understand where I should Image.onload to drawImage correctly?

My situation:

I'm loading my images from Json file and store them in array (imgArray it's the array with pictures links):

```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'img/img.json', false);
        xhr.send();
        imgArray = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
```

Than I create a function that accept my imgArray and makes new Images for every link and put them into new array:

```
 function loadImage(ImgArray){

    var pics = [];
    var img;

        ImgArray.forEach(function(link){
        img = new Image();
        img.src = link;

        pics.push(img.src);
    });
        return pics;
};
```

And for example I want to draw one of those images:

```
function draw(){ 
 ctx.drawImage(loadImage(imgArray)[0]),0,0,100,100);
};
```

The result of draw() function is the array with the new Image links, but I can't draw them because of, as I know, that they aren't loaded yet. 
Please someone tell me when I should do this?

Here is the link to the full story: http://jsfiddle.net/L23oam57/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recrusive call:

```
var counter = 0;
var pics = [];
function loadImage(img){


        var img;


            img = new Image();
            img.src = link;
            img.onload = function(e){draw(img)};
            pics.push(img.src);


    };

    function draw(image){ 
     ctx.drawImage(image),0,0,100,100);
     if(counter != imageArray.length)
     {
      loadImage(ImgArray[counter]);
      counter++;

     }
    };
```

Comment: I would queue up all the images at once as this will allow the browser to much better parallelize the requests which should result in 'more responsive' to the user. This benefit is also seen, but to a lesser extent, if the images are fetched from cache as it avoids having to "wait an onload event cycle". In addition it will ensure that all the images are attempted to be fetched even if some fail to load (ie. partial results or fast failures are better than waiting forever for an even that will never occur).

Comment: this is a queue only one file load, the other wait until  the current finish to be drawn on the canvas... if you want all together you dont really need a queue load every one like you did and call to draw and pass the object, this will happen in parallel but i dont really recommend this it can cause to browsers to freeze specially on mobile devices...